# BeautifulSoup truncates table

Tags: python, character-encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to write a Python script to process all the [joyo kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_j%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji). However, my script is only getting the first 504 elements of the table. The full table has 2,136 elements. This script demonstrates the problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_j%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

print soup.prettify()
```

The last element this shows from the table is:

```
   <tr>
   <td>
    504
   </td>
   <td style="font-size:2em">
    <a href="//">
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

However, when I look at that table in chrome, I see this for element 504

```
<tr>
<td>504</td>
<td style="font-size:2em">
<a href="//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%BF%80" class="extiw" title="wikt:激">激</a>
</td>
...
```

I expected the last element of the table to be element 2,136.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What OS are you using, and do you have lxml installed? What happens when you use `BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser')` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Getting the same output as OP when not using 'html.parser'. I'm on OSX and have lxml installed.

Comment: Adding 'html.parser' solved it! Thanks Martijn! If you write this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Ari: are you using lxml on Windows then? Perhaps installed from [gholke's Python modules for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) site?

Comment: I am using ox 10.10.3,  Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64) and BeautifulSoup 3.2.1

Comment: I am too, but not Anaconda. LXML is version 3.4.2 (see `lxml.etree.LXML_VERSION`) and `libxml` is 2.9.0 (`lxml.etree.LIBXML_VERSION`).

Comment: >>> lxml.etree.LXML_VERSION
(3, 4, 0, 0)
>>> lxml.etree.LIBXML_VERSION
(2, 9, 0)

Comment: What is Python's equivalent of R's update.packages()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a broken version of `lxml` or `libxml` (the actual C library doing the parsing) installed.

The page parses just fine for me on Python 2.7.9 with `lxml` 3.4.2 and `libxml2` version 2.9.0.

You can tell BeautifulSoup to use the standard-library parser with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
```

See [*Installing a parser*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) about the implications of switching parsers.